# Copy/paste first sentence of every paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word

As a non-programmer, here are my beginning, non-VBA, thoughts on how to copy/paste the first sentence of every paragraph:

Dim Terminalpoint as String

1. Terminalpoint = “.” Or “?” or “!”
2. Run through text until you find a terminal point
3. Select everything before that terminalpoint.
4. Copy selection
5. Insert copied text into a new worksheet
6. Run through text until you find a paragraph break or tabbed line
7. Repeat steps 2-6 until end of text

Can I do this using VBA? How can I get started?

Comment: *Select everything before that terminalpoint* returns the first *sentence*, not the first *word*.  Which do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of extracting the first **SENTENCE** from each paragraph in a document. This would be code written in and called from Word Application.

```
Sub test()
Dim doc As Document
Dim p As Paragraph
Dim s As String

Set doc = ActiveDocument

For Each p In doc.Paragraphs
    Debug.Print p.Range.Sentences(1)

Next

End Sub
```

From Excel, a simple routine to take each *first sentence* and place it in a *new* worksheet in the active Excel workbook:

```
Sub GetSentences()
'Word objects
Dim wdApp as Object
Dim doc as Object
Dim p as Object
Dim s as String

Dim ws as Worksheet

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set doc = wdApp.Documents.Open("c:\your filename.docx")

For each p in doc.Paragraphs
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add
    ws.Range("A1").Value = p.Range.Sentences(1)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I made a typo. I meant to say the first **sentence** of every paragraph.

Comment: OK, then do `p.Range.Sentences(1)` :)

Comment: First of all, thank you - this code does what I wanted it to do.
Secondly, why is "debug" necessary? Why can't you just begin that statement with "print"?

Comment: You're welcome. If this has answered your question, please do consider marking the answer as "Accepted". This way it can help other people with similar problems in the future.

Comment: To your follow-up: Try for yourself and find out what happens if you just do `Print ...` :)